# How can I make GUIMiner use the CPU for mining?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, cpu-mining

I am trying to setup [GUIMiner](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poclbm-gui) together with mining.bitcoin.cz. As I am working on a laptop with an Intel graphic card I am (probably?) unable to use GPU mining. So, just for a test, I tried to run GUIMiner without GPU support, that is as a CPU miner (if this is the correct word).

Clicking the `start mining` button doesn't seem to make anything run. I might be mistaken, but the lower right corner of the application keeps saying `stopped`.

The *console* tab says:

> 2013-04-03 17:51:51: Running command: poclbm.exe ***:***@api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 --device=0 --platform=0 --verbose -r1`

But no error message, either.

So, I go to cmd.exe and copy `poclbm.exe ***:***@api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 --device=0 --platform=0 --verbose -r1`. This results in

```
No PyOpenCL
Not using OpenCL
Nothing to mine on, exiting
```

which can be taken as an error message. I believe that "OpenCL" indicates that the program wants to use a GPU (although) I am not sure. I just want to test the mining functionality and see if I can particiapte in the mining pool, at the moment without graphic card, only the CPU. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: So which drivers do I download for an amd CPU. Cause a built in graphics card ain't gonna be able to mine bitcoins. Lol.

Comment: Sadly, you can't mine without GPU quickly. We both are sad brothers.

Answer (score 3):

If you start the bitcoin-qt client from the command line with the `bitcoin-qt.exe -gen 1` command, then it will generate bitcoins using your CPU. Alternately, use [cpuminer](https://github.com/jgarzik/cpuminer). ([Builds](http://yyz.us/bitcoin/))

Comment: I have started the bitcoin-qt how you stated it but guiminer still says it's stopped.

Comment: The solution I gave you doesn't involve guiminer at all, that's why it still says it's stopped.

Comment: But I wanted to involve guiminer.

Comment: The question was how to get GUIMiner to do the task.

Answer (score 0):

Download the OpenCL drivers for the processor you have from the official links;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#Drivers

I installed the OpenCL drivers for AMD and am now able to mine using my hex core AMD system CPU along with the GPU.   I installed the Intel OpenCL drivers inside of VMware fusion on my MacBook Pro and am able to mine using guiminer within VMware fusion in Windows 7.

For comparison,

I get 1Mh/s in VMware Fusion Win7 64BIT on my MacBook Pro Retina (early 2013) using the CPU.

I get 4.7Mh/s using GUIMiner inside OS X using the CPU and OpenCL.

I get 1.7Mh/s using GUIMiner and OpenCL for the CPU on my AMD X6 1045T.

I get 22Mh/s on my MacBook Pro using BitMinter and my GT 650-M GPU.

I get 17Mh/s on my AMD Win7 using GUIMiner and my nVidia 620 GPU.

I am a bit shocked that the 620 and 650 GPU results are so similar.

Comment: BitMinter's client might also just be slower.

Comment: Yeah and 15.4 with a GT9600oc :-)

Answer (score -1):

Install [Intel SDK for OpenCL* Applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk). I'm gussing it's a framework for [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). It worked for me.